# Can p values be used to determine the statistical significance of an alternate model?

Tags: machine-learning, p-value

Say I have an alternate model and wish to determine whether the increase in accuracy is statistically significant enough to replace an existing one. 
Model A, tested on 100 batches of 1,000 observations has an average accuracy of .80, and follows a beta distribution. Assume a similar distribution for Model B, but with average value of .84.
As such, my null hypothesis is that Model A is .8 accurate and Model B is not .8 accurate. I set a particular alpha and beta value which allows me to determine whether or not to reject this alternate model proposition.
Is this a correct way of systematically determining whether to favour an alternate model based on the accuracy of an alternate model versus original?

Comment: This is along the lines of how F-testing nested linear models works.

Comment: thank you VERY much @Dave